# Can I cache JS files across domains?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

So I have a landing page for an app, let's say at `foo.com`.

The app's at `app.foo.com`.

As it's a few mb, when on the landing page, I'd like to pre-load the app. I've tried to use the `new Image()` trick to get it in the cache:

```
var fileUrl = 'https://app.foo.com/static/main.js'
new Image().src = fileUrl
```

This adds it to the cache for the `foo.com` site, but when opening `app.foo.com`, it appears to still download the `main.js` file again.

Is there any way around this, or is it just how browsers work?

Comment: Client-side JavaScript is only cached by the Browser. So, if you're referring to the same file via absolute path, or correct relative path, it should already be cached by the Client's Browser. Why is an image src a js file anyways?

Comment: Just load from the same place on each website,. Eg.  From app.foo.com load the JavaScript from app.com.  This is why cdns are popular, eg if lots of websites used jQuery if they all use a cdn there is a good chance it will be cached.

Comment: @Keith it is loading from the exact same URL, but it doesn't appear to cache the file. Chrome's network tab says the file is downloaded each time :/

StackSlave, it's using an image src cause I don't want it to execute, only to download/cache.

Answer (score 2):

This is prevented by newer browser, as one part of storage partitioning, to prevent user tracking. This is also the case for CDNs, but wasn't years ago. For further details, have a look here:

- https://github.com/privacycg/storage-partitioning
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/10/http-cache-partitioning
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/State_Partitioning